# AngularJS http.post with cherrypy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, curl, cherrypy

I'm trying to post events into a CherryPy small app which responds to GET/POST but when trying it with AngularJS it simply not posting a thing.

Now, I don't know whether this has to do with AngularJS or with CherryPy (CP), cross domain is enabled in CP but it simply can't get the POST method. However this works with CURL

POST in CP is defined as:

```
    def POST(self, date, description):
    # read items to catch any server side update
    events = {
        "date": int(date.encode('ascii','ignore')),
        "description": description.encode('ascii','ignore'),
        "status":"Active"
    }
    # storing changes
    save_events(events)
    return ('Event created\n')
```

Headers are enabled by:

```
def enableCrossDomain():
cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, POST"
cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Cache-Control, X-Proxy-Authorization, X-Requested-With"

def OPTIONS(self):
    enableCrossDomain()
    return
```

And a CURL call looks like this:

```
curl -d $EPOCH_DATE -d $EVENT -X POST 'myurl.com:1234/api/events/'
```

Trying this with AngularJS:

```
var message = "'" + $scope.event_description + "' '" + $scope.datetime_start + "'";
            console.log(message);
            $scope.post_url = "myurl.com:1234/api/events";
            $http.post($scope.post_url,message).success();
```

Already tried posting "message" as a JSON and specifying it in the headers but just can't get it to work. Any ideas what am I missing or what else should I try here?

Comment: Maybe angular is passing in some parameters that aren't in the handler signature?

Comment: So the curl invocation works fine, but the `$http.post` invocation does not, right? If so I would try to capture the HTTP traffic over the network and compare to see if there are any significant changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer was quite simpler:

The URL was not properly encoded so the browser was going bonkers; changed this:

```
$scope.post_url = "myurl.com:1234/api/events";
```

For

```
$scope.post_url = "http://myurl.com:1234/api/events";
```

Then just the message was being wrongly parsed, that I noticed by the following message:

```
HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: message')
```

For the sake of simplicity changed the parameters to just one message and split it internally in python, then my whole POST call changed to this:

```
$scope.post_url = "http://myurl.com:1234/api/events";
var message = 'message=' + $scope.datetime_start + ',' + $scope.event_description;
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $scope.post_url,
    data: message,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

And important as well, on the python end I was not appending the headers to the POST message, changed the following:

```
def POST(self, date, description):
# read items to catch any server side update
events = {
    "date": int(date.encode('ascii','ignore')),
    "description": description.encode('ascii','ignore'),
    "status":"Active"
}
# storing changes
save_events(events)
return ('Event created\n')
```

For this:

```
def POST(self, message):
    # read items to catch any server side update
    events = {
        "date": int(message.split(',')[0].encode('ascii','ignore')),
        "description": message.split(',')[1].encode('ascii','ignore'),
        "status":"Active"
    }
    # storing changes
    save_events(events)
    enableCrossDomain() # HEADERS HERE OR AJAX GETS ANGRY
    return ('Event created\n')
```

Comment: Hey Ramon. I wonder if you can help me out. I'm writing an Angular app that makes REST calls to a 3rd party product (based on CherryPy). I'm using $http and all my calls fail because the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: header is not set. From what I've been able to establish you can set the response headers somewherein CherryPy. Would you happen to know where? thanks Mark

Comment: @mark1234 It sounds to me like you were having some CORS issues. I'd have a look at your OPTIONS verb definition (if available) sometimes the browsers stall over that point; if that works go ahead and dive into your HTTP server config.